# How to use array list ? [Oop]

Tags: java, arraylist

Implement Zoo class (with its test class). Zoo have name and area in meter square. Zoo can have one or more Animals. An Animal has ID, name, Type, Age, gender. We should be able to add new Animals to the Zoo, remove Animals and determine how many animals currently in the zoo.

This is the Zoo class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Zoo {
    String name;
    String area;
    ArrayList<Animal> animals;
    static int id;

    public Zoo(String name, String area) {
        this.name = name;
        this.area = area;
    }

    public void addanimal(animal ann) {
        animals.add(id, ann);
        id++;
    }
}

public class Animal {
    String name;
    String type;
    String age;
    String gender;

    public Animal(String name, String type, String age, String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Zoo nozha = new Zoo("nozha", "100");
        Animal lion = new Animal("lion", "male", "20", "fine");
        nozha.addanimal(lion);
        Znimal tiger = new Animal("tiger", "male", "30", "ssc");
        nozha.addanimal(tiger);
        System.out.print(Zoo.id);
    }
}
```

First I need help with function (addanimal) because when I print (zoo.id) its not working and I didn't know how to remove animal please help me i am beginner in programming and this is my first time i used ArrayList and I never asked before

Comment: It would help you (and others) if you complied with Java naming conventions, in particular: class name start with a large cap (`Zoo`, `Animal`), method names use camel case (`addAnimal`).

Comment: What is not working? What did you expect to get and what did you get. I would expect this to print `2` assuming you changed `List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();`

Comment: I would make all the fields `final` where possible. ;)

Comment: And you switched out gender and type when declaring lion and tiger (not relevant to the actual problem, no)

Comment: Seems like you asked exactly the same question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471563/how-to-create-two-classes

Comment: A related question [How to create two classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471563/how-to-create-two-classes)

Comment: Why are you incrementing `id` in add? If you need the number of animals in the zoo just use `animals.size()`

Comment: `id` should certainly *not* be static.

Comment: (The following is not meant to be mean) Stop posting duplicate questions. What you need to do is to take a step back and go through some introductions to java/programming. And it's worth mentioning that naming conventions are in fact a really huge deal. And you'll learn 10 times more if you figure things out for yourself.

Comment: I tagged your question as homework, as it obviously is one. Please do it yourself next time you're asking a question for a homework.

Comment: @JBNizet The homework tag should not be used anymore: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info

Comment: @maba: thanks forr that. I missed this deprecation.

Answer (score 8):

You need to initialize the `animals` variable to something other than its default value, which is `null`:

```
private List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
```

Then look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) of `java.util.List`, and you'll see that it contains methods to add and remove elements, as well as a method which returns its size, and makes thus the id variable completely unnecessary.

Also, notice in the javadoc how ALL the classes start with an uppercase letter, and ALL the methods are spelled in camelCase (like `addAnimal()` and not like `addanimal()`). Respect these conventions: they're a very important factor for the readability of your code.

Also, choose the appropriate type for your variables. An area, in meter square, should be an int or a float or a double, but not a String.

Comment: I would also add that it's preferable to initialize id as a 0, which is quite possible since it's static and preferable to avoid possible headaches if the class is ever to be extended/inherited from.

Comment: As I said in my answer, this ID variable is completely unnecessary, and shouldn't even be there.

Comment: That's true, but I suppose there's a reason it exists. If no then your answer is fully correct.

Comment: Given what's being asked, at the top of the question, there's absolutely no reason for this variable.

Answer (score 0):

> First i need help with function (addanimal) because when i print (zoo.id)

Basing from  your code it seems that `zoo.id` would return the size of `ArrayList<animals>` why use the size of the said list instead `animals.size()` or by rule of *encapsulation*, `getAnimals().size()`. *This may return a NullPointerException, so intialize `ArrayList<animals> with a empty`arraylist`*

In removing a said animal in the list, you better go for `animals.remove(Animal ann)`.

In updating, check for if `animals.contains(Animal ann)` is true, *via ID or hashCode* then check what index is `ann` in the list then update `ann` by `animals.set(<index>, ann)`

Answer (score 0):

Zoo.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
  public class Zoo {

    String name; 
    double area; 
    int sizeOfZoo = 0;
    ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();


    public Zoo(String name, double area) { 
        this.name = name; 
        this.area = area;

    }   

        public void addAnimal(Animal ann) {
        animals.add(ann); 
    } 

        public int getSizeOfZoo() {
                return animals.size();
        }
    }
```

Animal.java

```
public class Animal {
    String name;
    String type;
    String age;
    String gender;

    public Animal(String name, String type, String age, String gender) {

            this.name = name;
            this.type = type;
            this.age = age;
            this.gender = gender;
        }    
    }
```

Test.java

```
    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Zoo nozha = new Zoo("nozha", 100);
            Animal lion = new Animal("lion","fine","20","male");
            nozha.addAnimal(lion); 

            Animal tiger = new Animal("tiger","ssc","30","female");
            nozha.addAnimal(tiger);

            System.out.println("Number of animals in zoo: " + nozha.getSizeOfZoo());
        }
}
```

I threw in a getSizeOfZoo() method for you, to get rid of the Id variable. Changed String for area to a Double. Keep your classes seperate, keep the naming convention Class, variable, methodName()  etc. It makes it much easier to read.  The parameters when creating a lion and tiger were a little off, I've put it as name, type, age, gender now.

Check out the javadoc for ArrayList and you can figure out how to 'remove' an element from your ArrayList (I'm reluctant to do your project FOR you). The issues you have encountered are more around coding basics rather than anything Java specific, or OOP specific. Have a read up, try the mothod removeAnimal(animal an) and see how you get on. We can help if there is any issue, but look at getSizeOfZoo() and addAnimal() and the docs and you should be flying!

Hope that helps.

Comment: Maybe rename getSizeOfZoo() to a nicer name like zooPopulation() or numberOfAnimals() or whatever for your own sake and clarity.